# Cannot read parameter $1 using CodeIgniter URI Routing

Tags: codeigniter, routes, uri

I have strange problem. I have URI routing in my config CI like this:

```
$route['content/:num'] = "content/read/$1";
```

I also have controller class "content" with "read" method like this:

```
class Content extends CI_Controller {
     public function read($id) {
         echo $id;
     }
 }
```

And when I type this on browser localhost/myweb/index.php/content/1
It always echoing "$1" not 1.

Thank you for kindly help

Comment: Try `$route['content/(:any)'] = "content/read/$1";` And Check that the filename is Content.php and not content.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your route you missed the brackets around :num

```
$route['content/(:num)'] = "content/read/$1";
```

Comment: OMG! I didnt notice that. Its working now. Thank you so much